# Do you need to have Windows Server operating system for a web server

Tags: windows-7, windows, webserver

If you are setting up a web server for a handful of users to connect to over the web is it reasonable to just use Windows 7 or do you need to have Windows Server of some flavour?

Comment: as others have said, it should work. Just make sure to properly secure the OS, Disable Un-needed services, install a firewall,  etc if putting it on the Internet.

Comment: IIS on customer level versions of Windows is limited.

Comment: Comment if you want to close vote!!!

Comment: Which web server? The answer is dependent on that.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the hardware can handle the load, any OS is more than capable of acting as a web server. Generally speaking, a machine running Windows 7 can handle hundreds, if not thousands, of users.

Comment: IIS has connection limits on Win7. http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/5997/windows-vista-7-iis-concurrent-connection-limits/ and http://forums.iis.net/t/1164347.aspx/1

Comment: who said anything about iis?

Answer (score 1):

Really, no. You can use any modern OS. My suggestion is to install a Linux server of choice. You will get Apache installed with it and don't have to worry about buying licenses.

Server licenses tend to be more suited for running as a server - of course - and could have some benefits over desktop versions of OS'es. But the scenario you describe, a handful of users, is no problem for almost any computer to handle so when it comes to performance it shouldn't matter.

Comment: If its a Microsoft code base can you get that hosted with Linux by installing IIS somehow?

Comment: You can't install IIS on Linux - but there is a way to run .NET projects on Apache, see http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: Mono is fine for basic to moderate level .net apps, but there are compatibility issues and not all features, especially newer ones, are supported.  So you'll need to plan additional time for testing Mono compatibility if you go that route.

Comment: @BBlake I agree, if the existing web project is MS based, for the purpose CodeBlend describes, it might be easiest to run it on a Windows computer. Especially if he is most comfortable with MS OS'es.